# How to make every spot in the 2d array not have an equal value

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array and I don't want user input to repeat the same input
For eg in TicTacToe if they put an X in one spot and they input X again in the same spot. I want it to ask for another spot not equal to any previous ones
like if they had x in array1[2][2] they can not input array[2][2] again.

Comment: You should not have any event on the spot where user has already clicked...

Answer (score 0):

After the user clicked / input value for the array position, you could do a check similar to this:

```
//assumption is array[row][col] already initialized somewhere
var input_value = _________;//can be an "x" or a "o" for tic tac toe
var row = input_coordinate_y;
var col = input_coordinate_x;
if("undefined" !== typeof array[row][col] && "" !== array[row][col]) {
 alert("you've already made your choice on that tile please choose another");
}
else {
 array[row][col] = input_value;
}
```